# How should I respond to a client after receiving materials?

Tags: translation, business-japanese

A client sent some materials and I have to respond, so I want to give a quick thank you acknowledging that I have received the materials and will email again once I have reviewed them. (It's always important to get back to prospective clients quickly even if you don't have a proper response ready.)

For the "I'll review them and get back to you" part, I came up with the following possibilities, but none of them really seem right for a business situation

- ご確認して、改めてご連絡致します。     (Is して OK in a business situation?)
- ご確認の上、改めてご連絡致します。  (Just doesn't sound right somehow)
- ご確認させて頂きます。備えたら改めて連絡致します。 (Probably not this one, but I thought I'd add it for good measure)
- Something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that you shouldn't be using ご here because you are doing the 確認, not the other person.
Never use ご確認 for something that you will be doing. *However*, you can use ご for 連絡、報告, etc. when directing the action towards someone else.

For your example though, I might say:

> いつもお世話になっております。
>   XXの書類、本日確かに受領いたしました。 
>   内容を確認後、改めてご連絡いたします。
>   よろしくお願いいたします。

Also, out of the examples you made, the second one sounds fine if you take off the ご:

> 確認の上、改めてご連絡致します

Taken from [here](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/0/0na/05874300/):

> １ 他人の行為や持ち物などを表す語に付いて、その人に対する尊敬の意を表す。「―覧」「―殿」「―出勤」「―馳走」「―両親」(Used for actions done by other people, things that other people possess, etc.)
>
> ２ 他人に対する行為を表す語に付いて、その行為の及ぶ相手に対する敬意を表す。「―先導申し上げる」「―あいさつにうかがう」「―案内いたします」(Used for actions directed towards other people (anybody know a better translation for 他人に対する行為?))

As doing 確認 yourself does not fullfill definitions `1` or `2`, ご cannot be used.

Comment: For 他人に対する行為: How about "Used for one's own actions towards another to whom you feel obliged to show respect in the immediate situation"  (So, for example, if a shopkeeper goes shopping on his day off his peers in the same street might still use 謙譲語 to address him when he comes into their shop as a customer.)